# Trouble in retrieving the payment information on redirecting into my site

Tags: paypal

I have a website in CodeIgnitor an I am using paypal form for a payment transaction. On submitting the form it is directed to sandbox(for testing purpose) and all the product details are showing fine. Logged in with my another account, I clicked on the pay button. Now here, on clicking on Return to my site, there is a link "click here". Now here I am facing problem. When I am clicking on the link, I can get the payment information when it gets redirected to my site, but when I does not click on the "click here" and letting it automatically redirected , then I am not getting data.
 Please suggest, so that I can get save the payment records on my site.

Answer (score 1):

If your plan is to have data returned with the URL specified in the value, then you would need to include the "rm" variable.    For example:

---

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
```

Means - The payer’s browser is redirected to the return URL by the POST method, and all transaction variables are also posted.

---

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="1">
```

Means - The payer’s browser is redirected to the return URL by the GET method, and no variables are to be passed along

---

```
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="0">
```

Default setting - All shopping cart transactions use the GET method.

The "rm" variable takes effect only if the "return" variable is also set.

Source: http://bit.ly/1gZ7k9l

Comment: Yes, that I have included. I have included a hidden field rm value= 1. I have used "at" for setting the value of pdt (Payment Data Transfer ). Basically every thing is working when I click the link "click here", then only I am getting the return value from paypal , other than this , it is sending blank.

Comment: Well that right there answers your own question. You need to be using rm value = 2. Not 1.